# What are the limits for SharePoint field values?

Tags: sharepoint

Are there any limits to the amount of data that can be stored in an individual SharePoint field? If there are, what are they?

Is there a limit in terms of the number of bytes or string length, say, that can be stored as a value of an individual field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint stores the list items in a SQL Server table called `AllUserData`, so the maximum values are determined by the data types of the columns.

You can find the complete structure [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd358229.aspx). However, I cannot find any resource discussing the mapping between the SharePoint field types and SQL Server columns types; probably because accessing the SharePoint tables directly is strongly discouraged. That's not a big problem though - query the table, look at the results and you will be able to match the fields and the columns (e.g. `nvarchar1` correspond to the 1st 'Single line of text' field).

Comment: The AllUserData table is in the SharePoint_AdminContent database, for anyone else looking, by the way. This is brilliant, thanks!